# Using Object.Equals(Object) with a reference type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use the method `Object.Equals(Object)` to compare two different instances of a class I have created but what I need is to compare the value not the reference of the instances.

Researching about the subject I've found that I need to use value types, like struct, in order to be able to use the method `Equals` to compare the value of the instances and not the reference but I have a large library of classes so I'm afraid of change their type from class to struct because I don't know what other consequences could it have...any advice about whay should I do?

Can I override the method Equals for my class so it would compare the values instead the reference? I know it would be a lot of ways to do ir but what's the one that will give the best performance and "*programming correction*"...?

Comment: If you use structs, it will indead directly compare values. But it uses reflection, which is slow. In fact, if you want to compare values, always override the .Equals() method (for both structs and classes).

Comment: As you already said yourself, but I want to emphasise: Don't change classes to structs, or vice versa, unless you know the exact implications of this. Things can go very wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to override the Equals method and == operator of your class and in that write your comparison logic.

For more read 

[Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: An example or link would be nice. Also, if you override `Equals(object)` you should also override `GetHashCode` and provide an `Equals(ClassName)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'm overriding the Equals method, it will be hard because my class is very complex but if it is the correct way to do it I think it's worth it, the doubt I have now is: What happens if I don't override the GetHashCode right now, can I do it in the future if I need to use it?

Comment: Yes this the correct way. No downvotes to my answer. Only upvotes.

Comment: You should only override the `==` operator for immutable classes, because in C# this is widely understood to be reference-equality and can lead to mistakes.

Comment: @GuillermoRubio If you don't override `GetHashCode` anything relying on it will return incorrect results. You can override it to always return `0`. That's a correct implementation, but it will decrease the performance of dictionaries and hash tables *a lot*. Alternatively you can have `GetHashCode` throw a `NotImplementedException`. That way you'll notice if any code relies on `GetHashCode`.

Comment: My class is non-immutable so I'll implement method `Equals`, also this have a lot of members that are `List<>`of my own classes also, but less complex, obviously I have to override the `Equals` method also in those, before do it in the owner class

Comment: @CodesInChaos Now I need to compare the values (and structure) of two DataTable and i'm wondering if it's a good idea to create a new class that inherits from DataTable and override the Equals method there, or just create a method that compares the two DataTable cell by cell

Comment: @GuillermoRubio Personally I don't like overriding `Equals` on mutable types. I prefer helper methods or helper classes implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`